# The transitivity of the convergence in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, asymptotics, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

I am considering the following problem:

Let $F_n(\boldsymbol{\theta})$ is a sequence of random variables depending on a set of parameters $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ and the function mapping from  $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ to $F_n$ is continuous. Now assume that 
$$F_n(\boldsymbol{\theta})\overset{P}{\to}F(\boldsymbol{\theta})$$
and
$$\boldsymbol{\theta}_n\overset{P}{\to}\boldsymbol{\theta}\,$$.

Then would the following be correct?
$$F_n(\boldsymbol{\theta}_n)\overset{P}{\to}F(\boldsymbol{\theta})\,$$.

If it is correct, could anyone provide a proof of this? Thanks!

Comment: You might want to add continuity conditions for the way $F_n$ depend on $\theta$. If no such assumption is made, the statement is clearly false.

Comment: @Vim thanks for mentioning this. Just added the condition, any idea how to prove the final statement?

Comment: my idea would be to show $F_n(\theta_n)\to F_n(\theta)$ in probability.

Comment: A little bit reflection makes me believe you need stronger conditions: the mappings $F_n(\theta)$ are equicontinuous.

Comment: This isn't even necessarily true if $\theta_n$ is deterministic!

Comment: Could you be a little more precise about what "$F_n(\theta)\to F(\theta)$ in probability" means?  Are you regarding the functions $F_n$  to be random elements in some space of functions?  If so, with what topology?